# Figure out which recordType cause permission error in CloudKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, cloudkit

I get this error when modifing a records, but has no clue which recordType it raise the exception. Any idea to figure it out?

```
[NSDebugDescription: CKInternalErrorDomain: 1011, RequestUUID: 5BF276EF-2246-4B7C-A80B-C085FB74F084, ContainerID: iCloud.com.xxx, NSUnderlyingError: <CKError 0x15eb1a80: "Partial Failure" (1011); "Failed to modify some records"; partial errors: {
    tt0172495:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__) = <CKError 0x15dddf10: "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server message = "WRITE operation not permitted">
}>, CKPartialErrors: {
    "<CKRecordID: 0x15e607a0; tt0172495:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>" = "<CKError 0x15dddf10: \"Permission Failure\" (10/2007); server message = \"WRITE operation not permitted\"; uuid = 5BF276EF-2246-4B7C-A80B-C085FB74F084; container ID = \"iCloud.com.xxx\">";
}, CKErrorDescription: Failed to modify some records, NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to modify some records]
```

and using this method:

```
let mro = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: recordsToSave, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete)
mro.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = {saveRecords, deleteRecordsID, error in
```

Btw what happens if user wants to write  record and a record with same recordID already exist in CloudKit, but users has no right to modify that recordType?

What if the to records has exact the same attributes, so basically the operation would have no effect. Could it raise such an exception?